# How many times was Boone lied to?

Tags: lost

I recently watched the commentary-enabled version of *LOST*'s pilot. During the scene where Jack and Kate lied about what happened when they found the front of the plane, one of the showrunners said something along the lines of "This is the first of many times that Boone was lied to."

I don't really remember Boone ever being lied to, besides by Shannon in the flashbacks and a few other examples that occurred after the commentary was recorded. How many examples of people lying, or being less than honest to, Boone are there?

> Ghost Boone and Flash Sideways Boone also count.

Comment: You mean Shannon?